# Unable to restore from drive

Tags: backup, factory-reset, restore, google-drive

I have an old phone (Asus zenfone) that makes regular backups on drive. If I log on drive from pc I see the backup folder.

I need to restore data to my new phone (Samsung galaxy s7 edge).

The new phone is freshly formatted. When I add my Google account everything is fine (I also receive the email warning for login in new device) but the phone proposes restore from Samsung cloud only.

Actually I also had another backup on drive (made with a third phone) and at the first attempt the new phone proposed to restore from that backup.
Of course I declined, I deleted that backup from drive (keeping only the one I need) and finally retried the restore.

So it seems that the login to Google works but the phone ignores the existing backup.

What could I do to force the restore?

Comment: Try factory reset and start all over again (before you do that, sign out  device from Google account else you will run into FRP problems)

Comment: I suppose sign out is needed (and I did it), but in my case I had to perform also Android upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. The old phone has Oreo, the new one had Nougat.

I upgraded the new phone to Oreo, made a factory reset and finally the restore started correctly.